# Why this while loop does not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

Thanks everyone! I changed my code, and it still gives the error:

> list index out of range.

Why?

```
M  = []
B = [1, 3, 5]
C = [2, 4, 6]
while (B and C):
    if B[0] <= C[0]: 
        M.append(B.pop(0))
    if C[0] <= B[0]: 
        M.append(C.pop(0))

print('Updated list: ', M)
```

`

Comment: Have you stepped through it with a debugger, or print statements?

Comment: yes, it just kept running forever...

Comment: What did debugging tell you? It's running for a reason, and debugging will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: What do you expect "B and C" to return ? Using the interactive prompt this returns the contents of C which is non-zero and results in the condition not evaluating to False.

Comment: debugging did not tell me anything. Just keep running. When I checked it later, it showed "stopped running". That's it.

Comment: Try adding a print statement before the if statement so you can see what your program is doing.

Comment: [pythontutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) is what I use for working out things like this.

Comment: Please accept an answer if one (or more) of them gave you the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can debug by printing to observe what is happening in the code:

```
Before Popping: 
======================================
B and C:  [2, 4, 6]
B:  [1, 3, 5]
C:  [2, 4, 6]
======================================
Enters B[0] <= C[0] since 1 <= 2
B[0] = "1" is popped out

New value for B and C: 
B:  [3, 5]
C:  [2, 4, 6]

======================================
Enters C[0] <= B[0] since 2 <= 3
C[0] = "2" is popped out

New value for B and C: 
B:  [3, 5]
C:  [4, 6]

After Popping: 
*****************************************
B and C:  [4, 6]
B:  [3, 5]
C:  [4, 6]
*****************************************
Before Popping: 
======================================
B and C:  [4, 6]
B:  [3, 5]
C:  [4, 6]
======================================
Enters B[0] <= C[0] since 3 <= 4
B[0] = "3" is popped out

New value for B and C: 
B:  [5]
C:  [4, 6]

======================================
Enters C[0] <= B[0] since 4 <= 5
C[0] = "4" is popped out

New value for B and C: 
B:  [5]
C:  [6]

After Popping: 
*****************************************
B and C:  [6]
B:  [5]
C:  [6]
*****************************************
Before Popping: 
======================================
B and C:  [6]
B:  [5]
C:  [6]
======================================
Enters B[0] <= C[0] since 5 <= 6
B[0] = "5" is popped out

New value for B and C: 
B:  []
C:  [6]

======================================
```

Finally, it gets `IndexError: list index out of range` since, `B` is `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

B and C converge to:

```
B = [4, 5]
C = [2, 3, 6]
```

`C[0]` (2) is clearly not greater or equal to than `B[0]` (4)

so your branch to pop B stops being hit, and you get stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: Thanks! I changed the code but it did not work still :(

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop, you are using the and operator on B and C. As per Reference 5.1 of Python 2.7, only empty arrays would yield False.

https://docs.python.org/release/2.7.13/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

As suggested by Mark, subsequent to your first pop, the condition B[0] <= C[0] is no longer true and therefore no more element is popped. This, in turn, means that neither B or C ever reaches a point where it is empty. Therefore, there is no possibility to exit this loop.

Answer (score 0):

**What Went Wrong:**
the third time of the while loop after you do `B.pop(0)` the list `B` becomes empty. So when you call `B[0]` on the next line when list `B` is already empty you get an error `IndexError: list index out of range`

**Explain with Print Statement:**

I added some print statements in your code

```
M  = []
B = [1, 3, 5]
C = [2, 4, 6]
while (B and C):
    print("==============")
    if B[0] <= C[0]: 
        M.append(B.pop(0))
    print("B: " + str(B))
    if C[0] <= B[0]: 
        M.append(C.pop(0))
    print("C: " + str(C))
```

the result I get is:

```
==============
B: [3, 5]
C: [4, 6]
==============
B: [5]
C: [6]
==============
B: []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 9, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

see when `B` is already empty you cannot call `B[0]`. When you try to get an element from a list with `list[x]`. x has to be between 0 and size of the list - 1.

**Suggestion:**
I would strongly encourage you to learn how to use [print to debug your code](https://www.codementor.io/yetanotherallisonf/how-to-debug-python-code-beginners-print-line-du107ltvx). It is very useful. especially in a procedural language like Python.

Comment: No problem I am glad to help. I hope this helps you get a better understanding of what was wrong with your code. Welcome to StackOverflow. If you find this answer of any other helpful and solves your problem please mark it as the solution. That way it will help the community and fellow programmers who run into the same question as you in the future. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Because eventually you end up at a point in your code where one of your lists is empty - so it does not *have* an index 0 to reference. Specifically the 5 in list `B` is the last element of that list 'consumed' - copied to `M` and deleted from `B`, after which the list has no index 0.

I see two ways around this:

The first solution below solves your problem, in which you don't have a case where `B` and `C` exist at the start of your while loop to trigget the `B and C` to return `False` and break you out of the loop.Eventually, in `B[0] <= C[0]` the 5 in `B` is deleted, and the code moves next to `C[0] <= B[0]` whereupon it errors because `B` is empty. The code functions the same way in that if `B[0] <= C[0]` that part of the code runs, and if not (in which case `C[0] <= B[0]` is true) executes the code in your original second `if` statement without testing this that condition.

This means the `while` loop runs more times, because it only ever does one operation per cycle, but it means it tests `while (B and C)` after each change to a list, which avoids trying to do an operation on an empty list index, as `B` or `C` will evaluate to false if they are empty, and the while loop will exit.

```
M = []
B = [1, 3, 5]
C = [2, 4, 6]
while (B and C):
    if B[0] <= C[0]:
        M.append(B.pop(0))
    else:
        M.append(C.pop(0))

print('Updated list: ', M)
```

The second solution I came up with (which I came up with first, and while more explicit, is less simple) is to specifically specify that both `B` and `C` need to have something in them (ie have to have an index 0) before running each of the `if` statements in your original code, and if either is empty, to break out of the while loop before the `if` statement that throws the error can run:

```
M = []
B = [1, 3, 5]
C = [2, 4, 6]

while (B and C):
    if len(B) == 0 or len(C) == 0:
        break
    if B[0] <= C[0]:
        M.append(B.pop(0))
    if len(B) == 0 or len(C) == 0:
        break
    if C[0] <= B[0]:
        M.append(C.pop(0))

print('Updated list: ', M)
```

You could add this code in after your `while` loop and before your `print` function in either case, to ensure all of the list items is added to `M`:

```
D = B+C
M.append(D.pop(0))
```

Basically this just adds the list which is empty to the list with one item, with the new list, `D` having a single item in it at index 0, and then appending that to `M`.

Comment: Tests for len on B and C are redundant with the while condition.

Comment: Why? What I did stops the issue?

Comment: The first test in the loop is redundant with the while condition. It is your addition of the second test that makes things work better. And `if len(B) == 0` can be more simply written `if not B`.

Answer (score 0):

CHange your second `if` to `elif`.

Comment: Not clear that that is the required output. The OP was just asking about a list index problem and infinite looping, both of which this fixes.